# Why my uWSGI cannot find my Django application?

Tags: python, django, deployment, nginx, uwsgi

I have been through numerous similar questions on this forum but my issue still beats me.

**My project layout**

```
/home/django/apps
    |- movehere_env    <--- Virtualenv. Everthing, including uwsgi is installed in it.
    |- movehere_store
        |- settings.py
        |- apps
        |- Other project stuff
        |- prod      <--- Stores settings for prod env
            |- uwsgi.ini <--- uwsgi ini file
            |- wsgi.py   <--- Python code which has the Django application.
```

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/movehere_store_uwsgi.sock
chdir = /home/django/apps
module = 'movehere_store.prod.wsgi:application'
master = True
pidfile = /tmp/movehere_store.pid
vacuum = True
max-requests = 5000
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log
virtualenv = /home/django/apps/movehere_env
#harakiri = 20
processes  = 5
pp = /home/django/apps
```

**uwsgi.log**

```
Python version: 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jun 25 2011, 08:29:14)  [GCC 4.4.4 20100726 (Red Hat 4.4.4-13)]
Set PythonHome to /home/django/apps/movehere_env
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x9922be0
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
added /home/django/apps/ to pythonpath.
ImportError: No module named 'movehere_store.prod.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 15050)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 15051, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 15052, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 15053, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 15054, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 15055, cores: 1)
```

**How I launch uwsgi**

```
/home/django/apps/movehere_env/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/django/apps/movehere_store/prod/uwsgi.ini
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not put quotes around the module parameter in your uwsgi.ini. It was a bug in the Django docs, it's been fixed.